# decompose the word disappearance

Tags: meaning

In the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary application I searched the word "disappearance" and it showed the word as:

> dis.ap.pear.ance

I think it decomposed the word to *dis+ap+pear+ance*
I know "dis" is a prefix that means opposite of something and "ance" is a suffix that means "in the action of something"

But what is the meaning of "ap" and "pear" in the word disappearance?

Comment: They're syllables and (most of them) don't mean anything on their own.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for making it clear for me.

Comment: Actually some of them do mean something. _Dis-_ is a negative prefix, _-ance_ is a nominalizing suffix, and _appear_ is a two-syllable verb. The suffix is added to the verb, producing _appearance_, and then _dis-_ negates that to _disappearance_. The bracketing is `[dis- [appear -ance]]`.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of an East Asian language such as Chinese?

Comment: @BoldBen Yes I am from Iran. Why?

Comment: @Soheil0098 I was thinking of far East Asian languages. In Chinese and some of its related languages most syllables in polysyllabic words are actually complete words in their own right and most polysyllabic words are written as combinations of characters each of which is meaningful in itsellf. European languages aren't like that.  I'm afraid I don't know anything about Iranian but I suspect that it's more like a European than an East Asian language. I could imagine a Chinese person breaking an English word into syllables and expecting each syllable to be a word as it usually is in Chinese.

Comment: @BoldBen Good information. And yes you are right about persian language.